# NuGet adding/updating web.config instead of overwriting?

Tags: visual-studio, web-config, nuget

I just added Google Charts to my project and got the question from NuGet if I would like to overwrite my `web.config`. Since there was no, add/update option I chose **no** at first -> copied my `web.config` content -> Overwrite `web.config` this time -> Edited my `web.config` manually which didn't took all that long.

However, this still is prone to errors and copy/pasting like that is kinda tedious. So is there a way NuGet can add config data to `web.config` if it does not already exist instead of overwriting the complete file?

Comment: Did it end up actually overwriting your web.config? Or did it just add its content?

Comment: @mason It overwrote everything, my ConnectionsString and all other stuff specific for my project was gone.

Comment: Then I would think that the package publisher screwed up when they were setting it up. It is *not* normal behavior to overwrite your web.config file. You should contact them and let them know that they need to fix it. By the way though, it shouldn't be a big issue if it did overwrite it - you should be using source code control software and a revert should be a click or command away.

Comment: @mason Well it did prompt me if I wanted to override in the NuGet Console. Not sure how I would revert the action with a single command, might be possible but I havent been using VS for a long time. Should I really contact Google about this?

Comment: Of course you should contact them. If they're tools are doing the wrong thing then let them know! I don't know what source code control you're using, but Git support is now built into VS. SVN support is available through free plugins, and there's probably support for other systems available. Don't be afraid to experiment and see what something does, as you should always be able to revert changes.

Comment: None atm. I'm also new to MVC so I leave bug reporting to someone with more experience. ;)

Comment: In that case, I recommend you learn Git as it's the most popular right now. Operating without source code control is dangerous.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109270/discussion-between-menno-gouw-and-mason).

Comment: @mason I know GIT, just didn't add it to my project. Just learning MVC so don't really need to create a repo for that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package publisher has the ability to include config transformations.  Might want to download the raw nuget package and see what its doing.  Might find your answer there.  Reference:  http://docs.nuget.org/create/configuration-file-and-source-code-transformations

Comment: The GoogleAnalytics.GoogleCharts.Net has a `content\Web.Config` directory which will cause NuGet to copy that directly into your project, and prompt to overwrite any existing file. As you suggest it should be using an XDT transform.